# Adding babel-polyfill to Webpack 4 configuration file

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I want to add babel-polyfill to my webpack.config.js.
Babel documentation shows how to do that:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ["babel-polyfill", "./app/js"]
};
```

However, in my webpack.config.js I'm using more than only one entry point:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
    'js/bundle': './src/scripts/index', // generates bundle.js inside dist/js folder
    'js/another': './src/scripts/another', // generates another.js inside dist/js folder
  },
}
```

It generates two different bundles inside **dist/js** folder.
But now, I don't know how to add the **babel-polyfill** to my **entry**.

I tried this:

```
  entry: [
    babel-polyfill,
    {
      'js/bundle': './src/scripts/index', // generates bundle.js inside dist/js folder
      'js/another': './src/scripts/another', // generates another.js inside dist/js folder
    },
  ]
```

but then when I try to build, I get this error:
**SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier**

Any help?

Comment: `import "babel-polyfill"`on each of your entrypoints.

Comment: Do you mean importing it in to my entry files like this? 
require('../../node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill')

Comment: no need for absolute path. Just do an import/require.

Comment: You forgot to quote babel-polyfill

Comment: When you use `import "babel-polyfill"`it is important that this is the first import in your file. I had `import React from 'react'` first and spent some time trying to find you the polyfill import was not working

Answer (score 1):

I found this thread because array forEach wasn't being transpiled when I was using the Babel loader alone, IE 11 was complaining. All I did was npm install babel-polyfill, then in my main js file I require('babel-polyfill'). Actually I didn't need to modify my webpack config. After installing babel-polyfill and requiring it, successful transpilation of forEach